# Gerund vs infinitive dilemma : "an innate passion to { light / lighting } a fire"

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I have to start a sentence where I cannot figure out exactly if gerund or infinitive is to be used:

> They say humans have an innate passion to light a fire.

Does that sound correct, or it would be more appropriate:

> They say humans have an innate passion to lighting a fire.

Comment: The second is ungrammatical. The first sounds unidiomatic.  'They say humans have an innate passion for lighting fires.'

Answer (score 1):

The idiom is to have **[a passion for something](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+passion+for)**

> Fig. to have a strong feeling of need or desire for someone, something, or some activity.
>
> - Mary has a great passion **for chocolate**.
> - John has a passion **for fishing**, so he fishes as often as he can.

The present participle "-ing" is often used after prepositions, therefore, the OP should write

> - They say humans have an innate passion **for lighting fires**.

When we talk about the activity of something as a hobby or as a habitual action, the noun is often plural.

> - It is said that teenage girls often **have a passion for** riding ***horses***